# Is it possible to drive the Damocles in free roam?

Tags: fuel

In the 2008 open-world racing game FUEL the Damocles is a the vehicle with the highest speed and fastest acceleration. It's an old-school dragster car. The only issue is, unlike every other vehicle in the game, it's only available to drive in one race in the White Flats region.

Is there any way to get access to it in free roam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [mod on ModDB](https://www.moddb.com/mods/fuel-refueled/downloads/fuel-refueled-2013-1) that claims to unlock the vehicle for use (among other things).

According to a [game wiki](https://fuel.fandom.com/wiki/Damocles), the debug menu allows you to access the car.  But it seems the reason the car is only available on the salt flats is because anywhere else, the car can outrun the speed at which the game engine can render the map.

> - On PC it's possible to unlock it with the debug console.

> Its speed pushes the game engine's limit (older computers & gfx cards may not be able to render fast enough).

I believe the mod also takes car of the rendering issues.

If you wish to just go the debug mode route, I found [a video](https://www.moddb.com/games/fuel/videos/how-to-enable-debug-mode) also on ModDb explaining how. you need to do the following:

1. Open your game installation folder
2. Find the file called usergame.tsc and open it with a text editor
3. Remove the `//` from in front of the lines seen in this screenshot:

   [image: lines]
4. Save the file, and run the game.
5. Press the <kbd>T</kbd> key to open the debug menu.

From there, you should be able to set your vehicle to the Damocles.

Comment: I appreciate the fast response on an ancient game. Unfortunately I'm actually playing on Xbox 360, still I'm sure this answer will help someone else

Comment: @PausePause the wiki also said for Xbox that "A popular glitch in the Xbox version of the game is to join someone you've recently met in online free-roam whilst you're in the event. It will put you into free-roam with the Damocles, but be wary of the rendering whilst at top speed."  Though considering the games age, I wonder if this is even possible now.